# text-align: center is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used javascript to change the divs but after changing the divs the style for the `h2` will not align to the center anymore.

HTML:

```
    <div id="land" ontouchend="changepage()">
        <h1 id="headersize">Fish Pals</h1>
        <div id="landingimage"></div>
        <h1 id="headersize">Tap Me To Learn About Freshwater Aquarium Fish</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="items">
        <h2 id="center">Aquarium Fish</h2>
    </div>
```

The id `#center` is used to center the text with text align center, I have tried using a `span` to put style into it as well and it would not center

```
@media screen and (min-width: 375px){
    h2 {
        font-size: 80px;
        font-family: lemon;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #center {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #items {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 50px;
        grid-column-start: 2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

The javascript is working fine.
JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changepage(){
        var land = document.getElementById('land');
        land.style.display = 'none';
        var items = document.getElementById('items');
        items.style.display = 'inline';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: items.style.display = "grid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#items` are positioned `absolute`, which implicitly calculates its and its children width. In order to center a text, the container of that text needs to span 100% of the available space. Below is a fixed snippet. I also changed `ontouchend` to `onclick` for easier testing, but feel free to change that back.

Also, not sure what you are trying to achieve with the grid.

```js
function changepage(){
        var land = document.getElementById('land');
        land.style.display = 'none';
        var items = document.getElementById('items');
        items.style.display = 'grid';
    }
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 375px){
    h2 {
        font-size: 80px;
        font-family: lemon;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #center {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #items {
        /*
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 50px;
        grid-column-start: 2;
        */
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="land" onclick="changepage()">
        <h1 id="headersize">Fish Pals</h1>
        <div id="landingimage"></div>
        <h1 id="headersize">Tap Me To Learn About Freshwater Aquarium Fish</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="items">
        <h2 id="center">Aquarium Fish</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure about the grid. Should we maybe just hide and show child elements of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript applies `display: inline` to `#items`. But as an inline element it will only be as wide as its contents - in this case as wide as the `h2`'s text, so `text-align: center` on that text won't have any effect. You should probably change that to `display: block`, which defaults to 100% width.

Also, the absolute position of `#items`  might place it at an undesired position (but we would need more info about the other elements' CSS to know more concerning that).